# Singleton pattern using PHP

Tags: zend-framework, singleton

I am trying to create a dynamic navigation class.

```
class myApp_Helper_Breadcrum{
    protected $navigationArray=array();
    private static $_instance = null;
    public static function getInstance()
    {
         if (!isset(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
    private function __construct() {
         $this->navigationArray = array();
    }

    public  function popin($popInElement){
        array_push($this->navigationArray,$popInElement);
    }

    public  function displayLinks()
    {
          //print array
    }
}
```

In boostrap I did following

```
$nlinks=myApp_Helper_Breadcrum::getInstance();
Zend_Registry::set('nlinks',$nlinks);
```

Now in my controller I am calling as follow

```
$nlinks= Zend_Registry::get('nlinks');
$nlinks->popin('Home');
$nlinks->displayLinks();
```

The problem is, even if this class is singleton the constructor is called again and again which makes my array to initialize. what I am trying to achieve is to keep pushing the items in the navigation array as I navigate the site.

Any idea why it is like this in **ZF**?

Comment: Well, that's weird. Of course, `__construct` should not be public, but even set up as shown it shouldn't be called there. Can you make it `private` instead - and get the exact line (and error) where it's called?

Comment: I changed it to private but nothing ..there is no error. The array is getting initialized again hence cant keep track of values, everytime I call $nlinks->displayLinks() function  there is only 1 array item. ..which is not an expected output. I think it should be able to store array values which are been pushed. any more suggestion to look in...

Comment: Ok, I admit I still don't get it. Can you add `var_dump(123)` or something like that to `popin` method?

Comment: if I print the array in popin it print the array value Array([0] => Home) and in var_dump(self::$_instance) in getInstance() return null.

Comment: someone had marked this question as -1 but I this is not yet solved. I am still looking for an assistance in case someone know what possibly the cause can be. thanks

Comment: Well, let's make it more clear then. From what I got here, you're trying to implement the following: when user goes to 'Home' page, 'Home' is pushed into Breadcrumb object; when user goes to 'Some Action' page _after that_, you expect ZF to _add_ this 'Some Action' to Breadcrumb object. Is that right?

Comment: Speaking of Breadcrumbs, why don't use the ZF's own [Breadcrumbs](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.12/db_Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Breadcrumbs.html) helper?

Comment: ZF's breadcrumbs need containers links hardcoded as array or xml file. where in we want it to be dynamic..so we needed a control over what goes in and what goes out in the breadcrumbs...but then this problem is also interesting...where in one class manage the instance and other can't !...

Answer (score 2):

PHP isn't running like Java would where you have a JVM to maintain the state of your classes. In Java you can have a singleton behave exactly as you describe, but in PHP all the classes are refreshed with each subsequent call to the web server. So your singleton will stay in place for the duration of that call to the server, but once the response is sent then you start over again on the next call.

If you want to maintain state through successive calls you need to use the $_SESSION to keep track of your state.

EDIT: 
My answer above deals with PHP in general and not the Zend Framework specifically. See my comment below.

Comment: Well, I just can't believe that's the correct answer, and the problem was the OP belief that PHP should somehow store the state between subsequent calls... But it's the only sensible explanation of the OP's problem so far. )

Comment: david, In Zendframework - bootstrap file i see  $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance(); the class implementation say it is ensuring the singleton pattern and on successive call to pages it manage the values. I am not an expert just a curious question... how FrontController is managing the values...

Comment: You might be correct that ZendFramework automatically takes care of persisting your singletons across sessions I didn't see a Zend tag so I answered from a pure PHP OOP perspective. In general Singletons are not a great solution to many problems because they introduce another global scope that can be difficult to debug and test. I'll edit my comments to reflect my assumptions.

Comment: @user269867 `on successive call to pages it manage...` - can you show the fragment where it's written like this? Because, well, it doesn't - without any additional tools (like sessions) each HTTP request in PHP is served like it was the only request.

Comment: @raina77ow : Well just place print_r(Zend Front Controller Instance); to different pages of application and I could see the array populated with all the needed values.!! You mean to say - it is achieved by sessions in ZF !! My questions revolves around ZF not PHP...I had already said that I agree on PHP behavior.The problem is with ZF. Kindly note this question is Tag with Zendframework.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your component as below:

```
class MyApp_Helper_Breadcrum
{
    private static $_instance = null; // use private here

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (self::$_instance === null) { // use strictly equal to null
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }

    private function __construct() // use private here
    {
         // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: did as suggested, I added var_dump(self::$_instance); in getInstance() and it return null always....

Comment: Sorry but this works ([live example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0Klx4U)). As you can see, the constructor is called once and the same instance `0` is reused. I think you don't tell us the entire story.

Comment: I agree that it is standard way to implement Singleton and it suppose to work but in my case it is not working. What all I have done I had provided the details. Class,bootstrap call and the call in indexController. Let me know in case you need more details. I will add up.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem.
The problem is that the persistence of your classes are on the request scope.
And with zend, you can even have multiple requests for a page load.

PHP is a shared nothing architecture; each
request starts in a new process, and at the end of the request, it's all
thrown away. Persisting across requests simply cannot happen -- unless
you do your own caching. You can serialize objects and restore them --
but pragmatically, in most cases you'll get very little benefit from
this (and often run into all sorts of issues, particularly when it comes
to resource handles).

You may want to use Zend_cache, for persistence

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is old, I would like to add my 2 cent.

Zend **DOES NOT** create a singleton, that persists across multiple requests. Regardless of the interpretation of the ZF documentation, on each request, the whole stack is re-initialized.

This is where your problem comes from. Since bootstrapping is done on each request, each request also re-initializes your helper method. As far as I know, helpers in ZF 1.x **CAN'T** be singletons.

The only way I see this being implementes ar you want it to be, is using sessions.